# Monotonicity of Volume and Surface of n-sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Source: Quant interview.

For any positive integer $n$, let $A_n$ denote the surface area of the
unit ball in $R^n$, and let $V^n$ denote the volume of the unit ball in $R^n$.
Let $i$ be the positive integer such that $A_i > A_k$ for all $k \neq i$. Similarly let $j$ be the positive integer such that $V_j > V_k$ for all $k \neq j$.

What is $i-j$?

**Attempt:** Given that $V_n = \frac{A_n}{n}$ then $\Delta A_n = n \Delta V_n + V_n$ which shows that $i-j > 0$. I cannot find a better lower bound or upper bound (without deriving the closed form and checking numerically).

Comment: Classic nonsense question for a quant interview!

Comment: Not two weeks ago someone asked the same question, also from an interview. Don't recall if it was marked a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15656/volumes-of-n-balls-what-is-so-special-about-n-5 but it perhaps could have been.

Comment: Is linear algebra an appropriate tag?

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510048/relationship-between-volume-of-n-sphere-and-surface-area-of-n-1-sphere